# Unable bundle a less file due to a less-loader error

Tags: webpack, less

*webpack 3.5.5, less 3.8.1, less-loader 4.1.0, angularjs 1.6.9*

I'm trying to build a bundle. Everything works well until I import a less file in one of the angularjs components.

```
import '../styles/angular-json-tree.less';
```

Less file content:

```
.json-tree-out {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Webpack config where I have less-loader among the rules:

```
/* global __dirname, module, require */
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      _: 'lodash',
    }),
    // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), // uncomment this property to enable minimization
  ],
  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './public/app/app.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist/',
    publicPath: '/public/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['env'],
        },
        exclude: /(node_modules|lib|server|test|migrations|seeds)/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
        options: {
          javascriptEnabled: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|png|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, // https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-webpack#usage
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        loader: 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery',
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    'fs': 'empty',
    'net': 'empty',
    'tls': 'empty',
    'dns': 'empty',
    'boom': 'empty',
    'hapi': 'empty',
    'inert': 'empty',
    'joi': 'empty',
    'knex': 'empty',
    'mysql': 'empty',
    'hapi-auth-jwt': 'empty',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {},
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      'lib',
    ],
  },
};
```

And the error I got:

```
ERROR in ./public/app/search/call-detail/call-detail-logs/styles/angular-json-tree.less
Module parse failed: /media/trex/safe1/Development/qxip/homer-app/node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1!/media/trex/safe1/Development/qxip/homer-app/public/app/search/call-detail/call-detail-logs/styles/angular-json-tree.less Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* Page Styling */
| .json-tree-out {
|   left: 52%;
|   right: 2%;
 @ ./public/app/search/call-detail/call-detail-logs/controllers/call-detail-logs.controller.js 9:0-43
 @ ./public/app/search/call-detail/call-detail-logs/call-detail-logs.component.js
 @ ./public/app/search/call-detail/call-detail-logs/index.js
 @ ./public/app/search/call-detail/index.js
 @ ./public/app/search/index.js
 @ ./public/app/app.module.js
 @ ./public/app/app.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./public/app/app.js
```

What do I miss in the webpack config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader) says to write rule for loading of less files like this:

```
rules: [{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
  }, {
    loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
  }, {
    loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
  }]
}]
```

Please note this is actually **one rule** using 3 loaders. You need of course also install all the loaders to make this work (style-loader and css-loader)